# Elasticsearch match query on tokens returns less relevant result

Tags: elasticsearch, search, token

Hi can somebody help me to understand how Elasticsearch evaluates the relevance of tokens? I have a field **nn** which mapping looks like

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "refresh_interval": "-1",
            "number_of_shards": "4",
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "stopwords_SK": {
                        "ignore_case": "true",
                        "type": "stop",
                        "stopwords_path": "stopwords/slovak.txt"
                    },
                    "autocomplete_filter": {
                        "type": "edge_ngram",
                        "min_gram": "2",
                        "max_gram": "20"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "filter": [
                            "stopwords_SK",
                            "lowercase",
                            "stopwords_SK",
                            "autocomplete_filter"
                        ],
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard"
                    }
                }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1"
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "nn": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fielddata": true,
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    },
                    "boost": 10,
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The nn field is **tokenized** via standard tokenizer. Next simple query works well and returns relevant result like "softone  sro", "softec  sro"...

```
{
    "_source": [
        "nn", 
        "nazov"
    ],
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "nn": "softo"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But if I need to add **should** condition to the query it returns absolutely no relevant results and previous most relevant like "sofone" or "softex" are missing. It returns e.g. "**zo soz kovo zts nova as zts elektronika as**" or "**agentura socialnych sluzieb ass no**"...
Here is the should query

```
{
    "_source": [
        "nn",
        "nazov"
    ],
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "nn": "softo"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "nn": "as"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "nn": "sro"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Why the should query result missing "sofone" and "softex" items which are the most relevant in the first query? I though the relevance is based on the token length which means the "sotf" token is more relevant then "so" token. 
Thanks.

Comment: you should read this page of the ES guide https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html#_querying_the_field . It will explain why you need to override the analyzer at query time in your case.

Comment: It looks the analyzer should be override to standard in search time. It consider relevant only the whole search strings. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should make an "acceptable" answer here.

Comment: I think your question have already be posted on SO but i have no time to check duplicates. If so you could delete your question. Glad that this comment helped you. Regards